How can I make a contact pay a pending contribution with Webform?
My special process implies that the membership and its fee is added first and then the user has to pay online.
Is there a way with Drupal 10 / Webform 6.3 to request the pending membership contribution to be paid? I can find the value and add it to a line item contribution but it will add a new contribution when I 'just' need to make him pay his membership fee.

Does it need to be a webform or can you just direct them to their civi user dashboard with a checksum, or similarly an invoice payment link?

it can be anything: we're already tried using this link ./civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=1&ccid=164&cid=23 but I find it in terme of UX very poor, it just says 'pay 100€' not even 'hi Demerit, please pay for your pending membership'. That's why I was looking in the direction of Webform to add friendly html text

In your link the id=1 is the id of the contribution page, so you can make a contribution page specifically for this and put whatever text you want there. You set that page id at administer - civicontribute - component settings.

if you send out a link with a checksum and cid you should get the form preloading with the data and a 'hi pete' type message
